# How to design method handling a Collection in Java based on the class type passed?

Tags: java, generics, collections, apache-commons-dbutils

I query a database and get a Bean class, which returns `ArrayList<Object>`. However I

```
public static ArrayList<Object> getBeanList(){

    String sql = "....";

    ArrayList<Object> beanList = DBUtil.getBeanList(sql, new ConfDetailsBean());

    return beanList;
}
```

In the calling function of above helper method, I have to cast `ArrayList<Object>` to required class before I can work the beanList:

```
ArrayList<Object> beanObjList = getBeanList();  //helpermethod call

ArrayList<ConfDetailsBean> confDetailsBeanList = new ArrayList<ConfDetailsBean>();

for(Object bean: beanList)
    confDetailsBeanList.add((ConfDetailsBean) bean);
```

Now, in helper method `DBUtil.getBeanList(sql, new ConfDetailsBean());`, ConfDetailsBean is hardcoded.

How to make the helper method generic, so that I can pass any Bean Object?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should introduce a (method-scoped) type-parameter `T` and explicitly pass a `Class<T>`, so that you could be able to instantiate `T` at Runtime.

Also, returning a `List` instead of `ArrayList` could give you more flexibility:

```
public static List<T> getBeanList(Class<T> clazz) {

    String sql = "....";

    List<T> beanList = DBUtil.getBeanList(sql, clazz);

    return beanList;
}
```

Having this, your code will shorten a bit:

```
List<ConfDetailsBean> confDetailsBeanList = getBeanList(ConfDetailsBean.class);
```

Comment: thank you.  got it working in some what convoluted way `ArrayList<T> beanObjList =(ArrayList<T>) runner.query(conn, sql, new BeanListHandler<T>((Class<T>) beanObj.getClass()));`

Comment: i am guessing `(Class<T>) beanObj.getClass())` is equivalent to `ConfDetailsBean.class`